# Moving a local wordpress site to another localhost

Tags: wordpress

I´m learning **wordpress** at home, so i created a site in my personal computer, in a **localhost**. Now i´m at work and i would like to continue my studies. So, yesterday in home i exported with the tools, all the things i did and copied the theme i created. I thought with this action it would be just an import thing but...not at all. Here i´m a **wordpress** site too, another site, and i would like just to add the one a did yesterday at home. Thanks

Comment: Did you move your database also?

Comment: mmmm no i din´t. Was that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data for wordpress is stored in a database (e.g. posts, user details, etc.), and the theme/ plugins in the wp-content folder.

This means that to create a new install you need to copy over the plugins, theme and database data (you can do this from the export tab in PHPMyAdmin; installed at localhost/PHPMyAdmin).

Comment: yeah but if i already have a wordpress site with a database i will lose all?

Comment: I can have a multiples sites in a single wordpress installation no? so i would like to add this new site.

Comment: Its easier to jut create a new wordpress install for each new site, with each site using a new database.