# Wordpress on USB: transfer XAMPP Wordpress Site from localhost to USB flash

Tags: php, xampp

I want to move my Wordpress site to a USB to show it to my friend on his computer and have a portable version of it.

Following the best instructions online, I have gone through the following procedure, though I still am not able to see my localhost/WordpressSiteName. A similar issue was described in [Moving a local wordpress site to another localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338490/moving-a-local-wordpress-site-to-another-localhost)

To move from my localhost to USB localhost I did:
1) extract XAMPP (portable version) on USB
2) move my WordpressSiteName to htdocs inside USB
3) activate computer XAMPP server and export SQL file of the myDatabaseName
4) deactivate computer XAMPP, activated USB XAMPP and imported SQL to new myDatabaseName
5) (had 'time exeeding' issues and followed instructions to edit the limits in php.ini and allow for a smooth import)
6) open localhost/WordpressSiteName/wp-admin without an simple error message, cannot reach site.

Is there anything else that should be done?
My system is Windows 10 in case it matters.

Comment: you need to be more precise with the problems you experienced:
1. what's the error you saw when you opened the website?
2. was xampp running correctly on the xampp admin page?

Comment: @y_nk I did some troubleshooting. 1) I tried copying the full XAMPP folder from my computer - it works there though I read online that I should use XAMPP Portable (a light version) which I am using on the USB. 2) I tried to establish a brand new Wordpress site from scratch on the USB and get the same issue, namely "Error establishing a database connection". As it can be seen in this screenshot (https://imgur.com/a/G6RakAH), this is the error displayed. I get the error both when trying to set up wp-config.php through localhost/myWordpressSite (my WP folder in htdocs), and by manually setting it

Comment: Hence, it does work with the full XAMPP version but there seems to be an issue with the XAMPP Portable version when trying to go through the registration. xampp-portable-windows-x64-7.3.4-0-VC15.7z is the version, downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.3.4/xampp-portable-windows-x64-7.3.4-0-VC15.7z/download?use_mirror=netcologne

Comment: When opening the portable version of XAMPP, do you have the control panel showing that the database is up and running?

Comment: I did at the time. For anyone following this thread, I did not bother anymore. I would not recommend installing on a stick, but - if you do it for work - use an online server. Much less bothersome for a few bucks.